# Rails app Postgres role doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I looked rails screencast and I have done:

```
brew install postgresql

initdb /usr/local/var/postgres

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

rails new ispiti_postgres -d postgresql

bundle install
```

I started the server and I got this error:

> Read error: ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "darko" does not exist

Then I tried this:

```
darko@darko-Lenovo-G570 ~/Documents/pokusi/ispiti_postgres $ bundle exec rake db:create:all
FATAL:  role "darko" does not exist
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ispiti_postgres_development"}
rake aborted!
```

I tried changing username in `database.yaml` in `postgres`, `darko`, `root` and subsequently command rails db but every time I got for example:

> darko@darko-Lenovo-G570 ~/Documents/pokusi/ispiti_postgres $ rails db
>
> psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

I tried with no username and still I got message that role `darko` doesn't exist.

I don't know how to access `postgres`. I try this:

```
darko@darko-Lenovo-G570 ~/Documents/pokusi/ispiti_postgres $ sudo -u postgres -i

[sudo] password for darko: 

postgres@darko-Lenovo-G570 ~ $ psql

psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Thanks

Comment: you declare `usernaname` your `database.yml` file?

Comment: I tried without username and with different usernames.

Comment: I think you have to create the database and a user in postgresql first? (`CREATE USER...` and `CREATE DATABASE...` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES..` some like (this)[https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Linux 32-bit and LinuxBrew can be installed only on 64-bit system. So brew command wasn't working.